# Sending Local Video using Data Channels + Media Source Extension API

Tags: video, webrtc, media-source, rtcdatachannel, peer-connection

I have been playing around with WebRTC peerconnections for a while but it seems I am stretching what's possible with peerconnections & p2p video (at least right now)

Now I have been looking at the Media Source Extensions API to maybe creating an alternative workaround.

Been playing around with the MSE API for the last week or so and so far been able to get a local .webm video file working - that is chunking the video file into pieces and displaying it on an html video element.

Next I tried having a node server chunking the video and sending it to the client, then the client working using the MSE API to show the video (an actual example of how MSE is supposed to be used for)

Now I am wondering whether it's possible to of sending a local video from the html video element over p2p datachannels then piecing the video together on the receiver client using the MSE API. This would almost be recreating what WebRTC peerconnections already do right now

Just wondering whether anyone has tried this yet since I doubt it's something people would be using these APIs for normally. I will be trying this out soon regardless :]

Answer (score 2):

You can check my answer here:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/34043828/4158710

It is a concept code, DataChannel connection is not made, but it is a start.

Comment: Please don't post the exact same answer (neither as direct copies nor as links) to multiple questions: it's either not a good fit for all or the questions are duplicates which should be flagged/closed as such.